# Input value sticks when changing structure in angular 8 ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am facing a weird issue in angular 8 ngFor loop.

On click of update button, weeksValueDoubleArray changes but view is corrupted with old input data. When the run the application, I change the starting values from the input boxes, and then I click update button. However, the changed value before update sticks around even after update.
[image: This is before editing text]

[image: this is after editing text]

[image: This is after clicking update button]
Here is the html code:

```
<div class="table-responsive mb-4 mt-4">
  <button (click)="update()">update</button>

  <table class="table table-bordered custom-table" id="mytable">
    <tr id="headerRow">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let wk of arrayOfWeeks;let i=index">
        <th id="arrayWks{{i}}">{{wk}}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
    <ng-container id="ngId" *ngFor="let currSample of currentSamples;let in=index">
      <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let weekValue of weeksValueDoubleArray[in];let i=index">
          <td>
            <input type="text" value={{weekValue}}>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

And the typescript code is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  public currentSamples: string[];
  public arrayOfWeeks: string[];
  public weeksValueDoubleArray: string[][];
  public weeksValue: string[];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentSamples = new Array();
    this.currentSamples.push("0", "1", "2", "3", "4");
    this.populateWeeksValue();
    this.arrayOfWeeks = new Array();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 54; i++) {
      if (i < 10) {
        this.arrayOfWeeks.push("WW0" + String(i));
      }
      else {
        this.arrayOfWeeks.push("WW" + String(i));
      }
    }
  }

  update() {
    this.weeksValueDoubleArray = [];
    for (let ind = 0; ind < this.currentSamples.length; ind++) {
      this.weeksValue = new Array();
      for (var i = 1; i < 54; i++) {
        let value = "";
        if (i > 31 && i < 40) {
          value = "yes";
        }
        this.weeksValue.push(value);
      }
      this.weeksValueDoubleArray.push(this.weeksValue);
    }
  }
  populateWeeksValue() {
    this.weeksValueDoubleArray = [];
    for (let ind = 0; ind < this.currentSamples.length; ind++) {
      this.weeksValue = new Array();
      for (var i = 1; i < 54; i++) {
        let value = "";
        if (i > 21 && i < 30) {
          value = "yes";
        }
        this.weeksValue.push(value);
      }
      this.weeksValueDoubleArray.push(this.weeksValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The point mentioned above about `<input type="text" [value]="weekValue">` is true, but I think you might also have another problem because you're using an array of arrays. The value `weekValue` in your HTML is perhaps bound to an inner array of the array of arrays, and then when you replace the outer array, the binding to the *previous* inner array remains in effect.

Comment: The problem comes even with single array. This ca easily be reproduced. We take an array and display it and then we click some button which changes the array. But the new values does not come properly as the last edited text will somehow come after clicking update button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets around the "value" attribute to create a property binding.

```
 <input type="text" [value]="weekValue">
```

Whenever the weekValue changes, the input value will change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the problem though angular is having, but I fixed it by putting code like below:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let weekValue of weeksValueDoubleArray;let i=index;trackBy: trackItem">
          <td>
            <input type="text" [value]="weekValue">
          </td>
 </ng-container>
```

The trackBY:trackItem does the job for me. In ts file it looks like below:

```
trackItem (index, item) {
return this.weeksValueDoubleArray ? this.weeksValueDoubleArray : undefined;   }
```